PowerShell Repository in Artifactory - Module not found
I am trying to setup a PowerShell repository for private modules on Artifactory based on this article:
https://jfrog.com/help/r/how-to-work-with-powershell-modules-and-nuget-repository/how-to-work-with-powershell-modules-and-a-nuget-repository
Registered the repository and published the module successfully.
Module is 100% valid with a manifest.
The problem is, the Find-Module and Install-Module commands do not seem to find it...
I do see it properly in the UI.
If I take the same package, put it on local\remote folder and register it as a repository, it works well.
I have tried
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 

No change.
Here's my script for registering and searching/installing:
$RepositoryName = "local-ps"
$RepositoryLocation = "https://artifactoryURL/artifactory/api/nuget/local-ps"
Register-PSRepository -Name $RepositoryName -SourceLocation $RepositoryLocation -PublishLocation $RepositoryLocation -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Credential $Credential 
Find-Module -Name "MyModule" -Repository $RepositoryName -Credential $Credential 

The credentials in the $Credential object are 100% correct as the same were used to publish the module.
I was able to publish the module using:

Artifactory UI
Publish-Module
nuget push

But in each case, PowerShell cannot find the module
Modules and Provider versions I have:
PS C:\> Get-Module -Name PowerShellGet

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                               
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                               
Script     2.2.5      PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCapability...}                                                          

PS C:\> Get-Module -Name PackageManagement

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                               
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                               
Script     1.4.8.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Find-PackageProvider, Get-Package, Get-PackageProvider...}                                                      

PS C:\> Get-PackageProvider

Name                     Version          DynamicOptions                                                                                                                                 
----                     -------          --------------                                                                                                                                 
msi                      3.0.0.0          AdditionalArguments                                                                                                                            
msu                      3.0.0.0                                                                                                                                                         
NuGet                    3.0.0.1          Destination, ExcludeVersion, Scope, SkipDependencies, Headers, FilterOnTag, Contains, AllowPrereleaseVersions, ConfigFile, SkipValidate        
PowerShellGet            2.2.5.0          PackageManagementProvider, Type, Scope, AllowClobber, SkipPublisherCheck, InstallUpdate, NoPathUpdate, AllowPrereleaseVersions, Filter, Tag,...
Programs                 3.0.0.0          IncludeWindowsInstaller, IncludeSystemComponent   

The repository is listed and trusted when I check both Get-PSRepository and Get-PackageSource
The error the Find-Module and Install-Module return is:
PackageManagement\Find-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name
'MyModule'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:8879 char:9
+         PackageManagement\Find-Package @PSBoundParameters | Microsoft ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...ets.FindPackage:FindPackage) [Find-Package], Exceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.FindPackage

If I use a wildcard, not results are returned
I checked this on 3 different machines and I am starting to lose my mind
Never had this problem with Nexus in the past
Artifactory version is Enterprise license 7.84.12 rev 73502900
EDIT
Verbose output for Find-Module:
VERBOSE: Suppressed Verbose Repository details, Name = 'local-ps', Location = 'https://artifactoryURL/artifactory/api/nuget/local-ps'; IsTrusted = 'True'; IsReg
istered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'local-ps', Location = 'https://artifactoryURL/artifactory/api/nuget/local-ps'; IsTrusted = 'True'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: Using the specified source names : 'local-ps'.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://artifactoryURL/artifactory/api/nuget/local-ps' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://artifactoryURL/artifactory/api/nuget/local-ps/FindPackagesById()?id='MyModule'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'0' for the specified package 'MyModule'.


Does Find-Module ... -Verbose reveal any additional details (eg. which url's it's hitting in the background)?

Added the verbose output
